# pygame Error With Display_Width Not Defined

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame and I am trying to display a car I made in paint, when I try to use it I get the following error about the width that I am setting for the car to exist. Help me fix it.

> File
>   "C:\Users\perfe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\game.py",
>   line 16, in 
>           x = (display_width * 0.1)
>       NameError: name 'display_width' is not defined

My code for pygame is this

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Hi There")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("mycar.png")

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.1)
y = (display_height * 0.3)

x_change = 0

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True


    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                 x_change = -5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 x_change = 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 x_change = 0


    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to use a variable named `display_width` that you haven't defined anywhere. And you haven't defined such a variable anywhere, so it makes sense that you'd get an error. So you need a line that does so. Since you're doing `pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))`, you can just use a hardcoded `display_width = 800` (and I'll bet you can find exactly that line in one of the examples you're learning from). While you're at it, you can change the `set_mode` call to use `…set_mode(display_width, display_height)` instead of repeating yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says `display_width` is not defined. You will need to assign a value to this variable before its use. Similarly, you will also need to assign a value to `display_height`.

You could make the following changes to fix the error and make it easier to change the height and width in the future

```
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
...
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
...
x = (display_width * 0.1)
y = (display_height * 0.3)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you have defined either `display_width` or `display_height` in your program. I would suggest defining them at the top like so.

```
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
```

then you could also use those variables when calling `pygame.display.set_mode`